# Asyc task finishing after execution of rest of code?

Tags: java, android, http, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

I am sending HTTP request to server using AsnncTask.I am calling one function `checkServer()` with three arguments. From this function i am calling a class 
    URLDataProvider().execute("url").get().

When i call `checkServer` then asynctask is called but after getting response code of 404 checkProtocol method is called. after that `OnPostExecute` method is called.

After that i again calling `checkServer()` from Post execute if response code is 404. But the rest of code is called and after that i get the response code of 200 Ok. May i know why `checkProtocol()` & rest of the code is called before the end of `checkServer()`.

Here is the code

```
checkServer("http","servername","firstlogin");

checkProtocol(host_ip, portnumber);
-----------Some code-------------
 new Thread(new Runnable(){
```

URL DATA PROVIDER

```
private class UrlDataProvider3 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{

    String ret="";
    int checkStatus;
    Boolean exception=false;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) 
    {

        HttpURLConnection con = null;

        try 
          { 

            HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);
            con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url[0]).openConnection();
                con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
                con.setConnectTimeout(20000);



            if(con.getResponseCode()==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NOT_FOUND && con.getURL().toString().contains("pdata/Login"))
            {

                checkStatus=1;
                return "done";

            }
            else if(con.getResponseCode()==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NOT_FOUND && con.getURL().toString().contains("cdata/Login"))
            {

                 checkStatus=2;
                 return "done";
            }

            if(con.getResponseCode()==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK && con.getURL().toString().contains("pdata/Login"))

            {


                return "done";


            }
            else if(con.getResponseCode()==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK && con.getURL().toString().contains("cdata/Login"))
            {



                return "done";

            }

          }

        catch (SocketTimeoutException ste)
        {

            con.disconnect();
            return null;
        }
        catch (IOException e)
          {





          }

    return ret;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);



         if(checkStatus==1)
            {
                if(SettingsChaned)
                {

                 checkServer("http", "cdata","thirdlogin");
                }
                else 
                {

                checkServer("http", "cdata","firstlogin");
                }

            }
            else if(checkStatus==2)
            {
                if(SettingsChaned)
                {

                checkServer("http", "pdata","thirdlogin");
                }
                else
                {

                checkServer("http", "pdata","firstlogin");
                }
            }

}
```

Comment: Definition of asynchronous?

Comment: res of code means i have some other code written which is after calling the async task. so rest of other code should not exceute before a task is finished but in my case it is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AsynTask will move your execution to another thread and your so called rest of code is written in UI thread and it will be called before AsynTask is completed.

If you want to execute rest of code after AsynTask do its job you should write that rest of code in onPostExecute

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        // background task
     }



     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        // rest of code
     }
 }
```

Change the parameters of AsyncTask accordindly

Comment: well i can't do that is there any other way??

Comment: then i have to know your exact requirement that only i can suggest you friend

Comment: my requirement is that i want to excute the rest code which is wrtitten after the fucntion which starting execution of async task when async task is completed.rest of code must be executed after finish of async task.

Answer (score 1):

"AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.

AsyncTask is designed to be a helper class around Thread and Handler and does not constitute a generic threading framework. AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of time, it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the java.util.concurrent package such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor and FutureTask."

With this in mind remeber if you have lines of code outside of the `AsynTask`  for example

```
{
    new LongOperation().execute(""); //This runs in another thread on its doInBackground() method
    showAToast(); //this is still in the main thread.
    //And so on...
}
```

the showToastMethod will run on the Main thread while the LongOperation() AsyncTask wil continue in another thread.

For a more in dept with lots of examples you can go to: [The Documentation here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Hope it clears your doubt.